# socket error in sms-transport-sender-in-wso2-esb

Tags: wso2, esb, wso2-esb

I am using SMS transport sender to send SMS through ESB.

But after some time I will get below error:

```
Failed sending submit_sm command {org.jsmpp.session.AbstractSession}
java.net.SocketException: Socket closed.
```

If someone face the same type of issue please help me in that.

When we restart ESB Server this issue resolve for some time.

Comment: "Socket closed" error may have cause because the ESB tries to send data using a connection which was closed already by the server. As a work around try setting <property name="NO_KEEPALIVE" value="true"
                        scope="axis2"/> in your proxy. So that ESB will not try to reuse the connection

Comment: still i am getting the same error. in fact i had taken the tcp dump to check whether we are able to hit Gateway or not. i found that request is not going through. any other configuration need to done.

Comment: Could you try sending messages to the SMS gateway manually without going through ESB to verify that messages are going through and connectivity is stable.

Comment: i check the TCP dump in that i have see the request going out.

Comment: might be transportreceiver configuration is not correct can you please provide the correct transport receiver information